# Character array and pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf, character-arrays

The code snippet is given as:

```
char *s[] = {"program", "test", "load", "frame", "stack", NULL};
char **p = s + 2;
```

We need to find the *output* of following statement:

```
printf("%s", p[-2] + 3);
```

What does `p[-2]` refer to?

Comment: There is a syntax error: `printf{...);` won't compile.

Comment: As @vz0 says, there's a curly brace `{` after the `printf`. It should be a open parenthesis `(`, instead. Don't worry - I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *s[] = {"program","test","load","frame","stack",NULL};
char **p = s + 2
printf("%s", p[-2] + 3);
```

- The variable `s` is an array of `char*` pointers.
- The variable `p` is a pointer to a pointer. Pointer arithmetics downgrades the array `s` to a `char**`, initializing `p` to a value of two times the size of a `char**`. On a 32bit machine, if `s` points to `1000`, `p` will point to `1008`.

The expression `p[-2]` is equivalent to `*(p - 2)`, returning a simple pointer to a `char*`. In this case, a value pointing to the first element of the strings array: `"program"`.

Finally, since `*(p - 2)` is the expression pointing to the first letter of the string `"program"`, `*(p - 2) + 3` points to the fourth letter of that word: `"gram"`.

```
printf("%s", *(p - 2) + 3); /* prints: gram */
```

Comment: Aren't negative array indexes UB?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try compiling your code? Once the syntax errors are fixed, the output is **gram**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s[] = {"program","test","load","frame","stack",NULL};
    char **p = s + 2;

    printf("%s",p[-2] + 3);

    return 0;
};
```

See http://ideone.com/eVAUv for the compilation and output.